# How in laravel with stripe-php get balance after payment?

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments

In laravel 5.8 app with stripe/stripe-php: ^7.50 when customer  pays fir provided services
it has code:

```
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY') );
    $user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first();
    $customer_id = $user->stripe_customer_id;

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => $request->amount * 100, // Say $request->amount= 50
        'currency' => $request->currency,   // USD
        'customer' => $customer_id
    ]);
    TransactionsTable::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'type' => $request->card['brand'],
        'amount' => $request->amount,
        'currency' => $request->currency,
        'transaction_id' => $charge->id,
        'status' => $charge->status
    ]);
```

And USD 50 is subtracted from customer card and is added to the owner of stripe account
(in dev app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY)
My questions 1) as I want to send email to owner of stripe account in which way can I get balance
of his after successfull operation? How ths sum is differ under test/live?

2. How can I check error in case of invalid operation? Say if customers card has no enough money or
   expired? In catch block with $e->getMessage() or are there some better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the Balance API to retrieve that: https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance
2. You need to catch errors in your Charge::create: https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=php

Also you should consider using Payment Intents instead of Charges: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration

Comment: Thanks,could you please 1) to point to api to get balance of the client? 2) In case when customer
recieves money from owner of stripe account have Iuse the same API/code with negative sum or other 
api must be used ?

Comment: The first link there is the API to get the balance for the Stripe Account - which appears to be what you're asking for.  I don't understand your second question.